# How to import data into a text box in a website

Tags: web-services, web

There is an internal Website in my company which contains a text box to enter the data and on clicking the button retrieves the corresponding result. Now I want to create a wiki which contains multiple links. Each  link which on clicking  lands me  on this internal website with appropriate data(based on the link selected) already fed into the text box. Please help me out

Comment: Are you able to change the internal website? What are the technologies that it uses? Passing values to the site can be done by including parameters in the URL like http://my.site.com/page?param1=value1&param2=value2 (might need encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). The main point is to process the parameter at the target site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem consists of may smaller problems. One of the problems is to display a text item on the web page with some data already in it. With `textarea` it looks like this:

```
<textarea>asdf</textarea>
```

With text `input` it looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="asdf" />
```

I believe you need a starter tutorial, e.g. [php + mysql](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql) or [ruby on rails](https://www.railstutorial.org/book).